# Error invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' -fpermissive

Tags: c++

The below is the code, but I dont know how to debuy it. Can someone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MmDS.png)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;




class CSample
{



    int *x;
    int N;



public:



    //dafualt constructor
    CSample(): x(NULL)
    {}          
    void AllocateX(int N)
    {
        this->N = N;
        x = new int[this->N]; 
    }
    int GetX()
    {
        return x;
    }
    ~CSample()
    {
        delete []x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CSample ob1; //Default constructor is called.
    ob1.AllocateX(10);

    //problem with this line
    CSample ob2 = ob1; //default copy constructor called.

    CSample ob3; //Default constructor called.

    //problem with this line
    ob3 = ob1; //default overloaded = operator function called.
}
```

Comment: GetX should be either of type int* or return int. You also don't have a copy constructor defined. Please make sure to format your question properly in the future, and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: "I don't know how to debug it" - please take a look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, it's an *excellent* article on debugging techniques.

Answer (score 1):

This method has the wrong signature

```
int GetX()
{
    return x;
}
```

it should be

```
int* GetX()
{
    return x;
}
```

As far as your assignment, you'd need a *copy assignment operator* to say `ob3 = ob1` which would look like

```
CSample& operator=(CSample& other)
{
    N = other.N;
    x = new int[N];
    std::copy(other.x, other.x + other.N, x);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: that's true and yet it doesn't explain the OP's claim that the problem is with the assignment line. actually, it isn't her claim, it's the claim of whoever wrote the code the OP copied incorrectly, sorry. so actually, you're right.

Comment: Would be helpful to explain how the error message says exactly this.